# Entypo in Angular

Tags: angular

Entypo SVG icon set requires some JavaScript to be added to the page:

```
const entypo = require('entypo')

document.body.insertBefore(entypo.getNode(), document.body.firstChild)
```

Is there a way I can add this to my Angular application in some sort of global file so I can use Entypo glyphs in my application?

Answer (score 1):

I too wanted to use `entypo` in my Angular project, so I created a package (similar to `angular-font-awesome`) for using `entypo`.  The package is called [angular-entypo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-entypo).  All you need to do is:

1. Install `npm install angular-entypo`.
2. Include the `entypo` font by a method of your choice.
3. Add the `AngularEntypoModule`:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AngularEntypoModule } from 'angular-entypo';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularEntypoModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

4. Use it as a component:

```html
<entypo name="phone"></entypo>
```